# Smooth scroll plugin for websites

Tags: jquery, css, html, scroll, smoothing

I want to add smooth scroll to my site,
Something like this:
http://dahz.daffyhazan.com/loma/food/

What jquery plugins exists for this purpose or maybe a code I should write.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about the jQuery plugin [SmoothScroll.js](https://gist.github.com/galambalazs/6477177)?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use iScroll.js for smooth scroll.